# WebView Content size issue in swift

Tags: swift, webview

I have a web view in a view controller which is loaded from a url coming from server. The content coming inside the webview is very small and unreadable.

I've implemented all the code but I'm confused as to why it is not showing properly. This is how content is shown, content start from under the header image,
[image: This is my view]

This is the code used to load the url in the webview:

```
    func loadWeb(webURL: String) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let url = URL(string: webURL)

            self.webView.navigationDelegate = self
            self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: url!))

            self.view.makeToastActivity(.center)
            self.webView.uiDelegate = self
            self.view.hideToastActivity()
        }
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        showActivityIndicator(show: false)
        self.view.hideToastActivity()
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        showActivityIndicator(show: false)
        self.view.hideToastActivity()
    }

    func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFinishNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        showActivityIndicator(show: false)
        self.view.hideToastActivity()
    }
```

Comment: Did you read about responsive themes? If your site is aware of user-agent can serve different sizes (style) for mobile, desktop and so on if is responsive.

Comment: bro the same link open fine on android device. i think issue is in my code. @user3344236

Comment: Again I repeat it depends on what user-agent your site receive from  device request. Look into your site css etc and see if it threats this user-agent (something like Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1). Maybe it has already implementation for mozilla like user-agent